# Find roots of unity

Tags: roots-of-unity

Find the roots of
$6z^5 + 15z^4 + 20z^3 + 15z^2 + 6z + 1 = 0.$

I know how to do this without the coefficients, but I do not know what to do in this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Apropos of Andre's answer, you should train yourself to instantly recognise the lower order binomial coefficients (using Pascal's triangle, for instance).

Comment: What's the story behind the title?

Answer (score 10):

Hint: We are solving $(z+1)^6-z^6=0$, or equivalently $\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^6=1$.

Comment: I got $(z+1)^6 -z^6 = 0$, but how did you get $(1+1/z)^6=1$?

Comment: Rewrite as $(z+1)^6=z^6$.  Any solution of this is non-zero, so we can divide both sides by $z^6$. obtaining $\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)^6=1$. To make further processing easier later, I rewrote $\frac{z+1}{z}$ as $1+\frac{1}{z}$.